# What is the format to specify an external EDGE Gateway ApiId in CloudFormation templates?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create or update a stack with the following CloudFormation Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters: 
  ApiGatewayId:
    Type: String
  ApiLayerArn: 
    Type: String
  JarLocation: 
    Type: String
Resources:
  Function:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: net.bitsandpaper.api.kiosk.PlatformChecker
      Runtime: java11
      Code: 
        S3Bucket: bnp-build-artifacts
        S3Key: !Ref JarLocation
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 5
      Role: arn:aws:iam::479832603967:role/bnp-api-lambda-execution-role
      Layers:
        - !Ref ApiLayerArn
  ApiIntegration:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties: 
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayId
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationUri:  !Join 
        - ''
        - - 'arn:'
          - !Ref 'AWS::Partition'
          - ':apigateway:'
          - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
          - !Ref Function
          - /invocations
      TimeoutInMillis: 6000
  ApiRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayId
      RouteKey: 'GET /kiosk/platform-check'
      Target: !Join
        - /
        - - integrations
          - !Ref ApiIntegration
```

The parameters are correctly passed by an external file, they look good in the Web Console, notably parameter `ApiGatewayId` has value `8548rqrsm5`. Yet during deployment I have a `CREATE_FAILED` for `ApiIntegration`, with the message:

> Invalid API identifier specified 479832603967:8548rqrsm5 (Service:
> AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException;
> Request ID: 84918a83-cf9d-48d2-acf7-18d9d2e4d330; Proxy: null)

The API is an EDGE Rest API, in the same region than the CloudFormation stack. The ID is retrieved by the CLI with `aws apigateway get-rest-apis`.

Am I missing something in the ApiId format? The litterature is very scarce when not referencing an API in the same stack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AWS::ApiGatewayV2` is only for WEBSOCKTES and HTTP types. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html#cfn-apigatewayv2-api-protocoltype):

> The API protocol. Valid values are **WEBSOCKET or HTTP**.

But since you are writing about `Edge-optimized` (not supported by HTTP api) it seems to that you are using REST API, rather then HTTP API. So you should be using [AWS::ApiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ApiGateway.html) resources, not `AWS::ApiGatewayV2`.

Comment: This was my problem, thank you. This is poor naming on AWS part...

Comment: @SilverQuettier No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It seem's like the A**WS::ApiGatewayV2::Route** is created before the **AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration**. So When it trying to refer ApiIntegration it is not yet created.

So you should try to use DependsOn attribute.

> With the DependsOn attribute you can specify that the creation of a
> specific resource follows another. When you add a DependsOn attribute
> to a resource, that resource is created only after the creation of the
> resource specified in the DependsOn attribute.

Try this below CloudFormation code:

```
ApiRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    DependsOn: ApiIntegration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayId
      RouteKey: 'GET /kiosk/platform-check'
      Target: !Join
        - /
        - - integrations
          - !Ref ApiIntegration
```

I hope this will help you out to resolve your problem.

Link: [DependsOn Attribute UserGuide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Abdul, it will definetly help in the future, sadly this was not the issue here. I added the DependsOn instructions to my templates however, thanks :)